# burn, freeze, unfreeze functions

Tags: tokens, ico, crowdsale

I wonder what is the purpose of these functions? could you please provide me with some examples.

```
function burn(uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;            // Check if the sender has enough
        if (_value <= 0) throw; 
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeSub(balanceOf[msg.sender], _value);                      // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply = SafeMath.safeSub(totalSupply,_value);                                // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

function freeze(uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;            // Check if the sender has enough
    if (_value <= 0) throw; 
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeSub(balanceOf[msg.sender], _value);                      // Subtract from the sender
    freezeOf[msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeAdd(freezeOf[msg.sender], _value);                                // Updates totalSupply
    Freeze(msg.sender, _value);
    return true;
}

function unfreeze(uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    if (freezeOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;            // Check if the sender has enough
    if (_value <= 0) throw; 
    freezeOf[msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeSub(freezeOf[msg.sender], _value);                      // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeAdd(balanceOf[msg.sender], _value);
    Unfreeze(msg.sender, _value);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Burn:

> up to the developer define the functionality
>
> Can transfer to address(0) or deduct the number of tokens from the balance

Thanks, Richard!

Freeze: lock up funds so they can't be used

Unfreeze: unlocked previously locked up funds so they can be used again

Comment: The `burn()` for an ERC-20 token just deducts the amount to burn from the user's balance (and total supply) - it doesn't send them anywhere :-)

Comment: @Richard Horrocks so it used to deduct an amount of tokens from a user,
I undestand that the purpose will be to deduct any remaining amount of the already created tokens?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. (Like "burning money".)

Comment: (And note that you could do this for all users.)

Comment: @Richard Horrocks you mean that this can be done to all users, so every user that has been sent tokens, you can deduct an amount of their tokens even if it is on their ERC-20 compatible wallets?

Comment: ERC-20 wallets don't hold tokens :-) The "tokens" are just a number inside the ERC-20 contract. The wallet works by checking the smart contract for the value associated with your address, and reporting it back to you. So it _looks_ like your tokens are in your wallet, but they aren't.

Comment: If you're the owner of the contract, and the modifiers are set up in such a way, then you can burn as many tokens as you like. But it'll depend on how you've coded your contract.

Comment: Good attention to detail Richard :)
Thanks for the support

Comment: @RichardHorrocks This is also true when i have transfered my tokens to an exchange wallet?

Comment: Hi @kos_tsak - yes, exchange wallets work in the same way. Your tokens exist in the smart contract. Whoever "owns" or has the appropriate privileges over the contract can change your balance. You don't necessarily have complete control over your tokens like you do with your ether. (For a normal ether account you hold the private key - no one else does.)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks, I am playing around with some contracts, and i have seen the following, an AdminWallet address is used that the tokens are sent from to the asking address, the funds(ether) aggregated on the contract's address and there is a different owners' address with no funds(ether), which normally the ether should be going to in the first place and not to be kept on the contract's address, why would someone do that?

Comment: Hi again @MSwezey. I'd been thinking about this over the weekend - I was sure there was something not quite right with my initial comment. (I'd had a few beers... ) The ERC-20 specification doesn't actually include burn(). EIP-621 (which is still open) attempts to extend the ERC-20 standard to include a burn() and mint() functionality to decrease or increase the supply. In that specification, the burn is indeed a transfer to address 0. (Again, the specification hasn't been adopted.)

Comment: However, if you look at the burnable token implementation by Open Zeppelin (which is another example of how a burn could be done), the burn works by just decreasing values in the contract, which is what the example code in the question does. So, two different ways to implement it in the literature...

Comment: So, as I mentioned, the ERC-20 specification doesn't actually include burn(), so there are no restrictions on how it can be implemented. So what I told you is technically incorrect. The _OP's code_ doesn't send to address 0, but there's nothing to say that an ERC-20 contract with an additional burn function can't be implemented by sending to address 0.

Comment: Noted - let me reflect that. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function burn(uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;            // Check if the sender has enough
        if (_value <= 0) throw; 
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeSub(balanceOf[msg.sender], _value);                      // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply = SafeMath.safeSub(totalSupply,_value);                                // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }
```

The function burns YOUR token. It's not true what @Richard Horrocks wrote. You can only burn your own tokens and not from others. For example if you are making an ICO and own all token, you pay out the token that are sold. Some would keep the remaining, not sold, token and that would give you some power you maybe do not deserve. With this burn function you would simply remove the _value (that you enter before) from your balance without it getting transferred to someone else. It's like calculating 10-5. It's 5 but the other 5 is simply gone. With this function you can't burn from others than your token balance.

In my opinion both freeze and unfreeze make no sense. There is no limit at all for example about how long you want to freeze them. Those functions seem useless for me.

Comment: So the function the way it is, removes any remaining tokens that are on the owner's balance, instead of freeze unfreeze functions, maybe should be better to use a function to lock the tokens?

Comment: Yes, the function just removes the balance and the user can get it back with unfreeze. But there is no sense as it would be just wasting of gas. It would be other, if the function for example locks the amount for some days or like this. Or the function would also make sense (but then would be very dangerous) if it freezes the funds of other users and only owner could run it.

Comment: I am playing around with some contracts, and i have seen the following, an AdminWallet address is used that the tokens are sent from to the asking address, the funds(ether) aggregated on the contract's address and there is a different owners' address with no funds(ether), which normally the ether should be going to in the first place and not to be kept on the contract's address, why would someone do that?

Comment: I do not exactly understand what you mean but when someone sends funds to a contract address, it is not instantly on the owners address. To be exact, if there is no "withdraw" function or any function that pays the ethers instantly to someone (the owner address), the ethers sent to the contract will be lost forever.

Comment: with my wallet I sent 1 ether to a contract address, the address that it seems to be sending the tokens is 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 to my wallet address.
But the ether is kept on the contract's address balance rather than the owners address.

Comment: Hi there @dkb - can you explain why what I said about the ERC-20 `burn()` function is incorrect? We seem to be saying exactly the same thing... (Perhaps my use of "user" should have read "caller"?)

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you were getting at. You mean the part where I said the owner of the contract can burn any number of tokens they like? This was hypothetical, and I clarified it by saying it would depend on how you had coded your contract. I think what I didn't make clear was that `burn()` isn't actually part of the ERC-20 specification, so there are no restrictions on how it can be implemented as there are with the other functions. In the example code you gave (one implementation),  yes, only the owner of that particular address can burn their tokens, not the contract owner.

Comment: Other implementations of `burn()` could well allow the contract owner to burn the tokens belonging to any or all addresses. (Yes, people might not be happy about that power, which is why you should ideally check the contract code before sending money to a token contract.)

Comment: @Richard Horrocks: Sorry, for sure you're right that a contract developer could develop the contract in a way where he can steal or burn tokens from others. It was not in this case, but for sure is possible.

Comment: @dkb: Okay, no worries - thanks for confirming we're on the same page :-)

Comment: @kos_tsak: I think you do not understand some basics yet, as I did not. It's important to differentiate between a contract and owner address. More detailed, a contract address can never be accessed directly (no private key). If I write a contract, I can add a function that if the contract receives ethers that came not through a function (for example a deposit()-function) but were directly paid, that those ethers get returned to the payer. But if I do not add such a repay-/revert- function, the ethers would be lost in the wallet forever. They then can not even be accessed by the contract owner.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks thank you too, it was just a matter of making it clear for the user here :p. I am sure you know a bit more than me ;)

Comment: Thanks @dkb. By being here you already know more than most people who've heard of Ethereum :-) And there's so much to learn. Which is why it's so much fun :-)

Comment: That's true, learning Solidity is really a great opportunity :)

Comment: Thank you both of you, I am still trying to figure out a lot of things, also @dkb as you mentioned if the ether is kept on contracts wallet cannot be accessed, but I have run the code that I was talking about and the implementation was as I said, I guess there will be another function that will transfer the ether to the owner wallet address maybe after the crowdsale is over

Comment: That for sure can be possible. Look at the contract source, maybe you find something :) If you want, you can post the contract address here and we'll have a look on it.